# Серая карта Google Maps в Magnific Popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, popup

Здравствуйте!

Я использую библиотеку [Magnific Popup](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) для отображения всплывающих окон с фотографиями.

Мне также необходимо выводить Google карту **под** фотографией. Для реализации этой идеи я использую следующий код:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: { src: 'http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/', type: 'image' },
    image: { markup: '' +
        '<div class="mfp-figure">' +
        '    <div class="mfp-close"></div>' +
        '    <div class="mfp-img"></div>' +
        '    <div class="mfp-bottom-bar"><div id="map"></div></div>' +
        '</div>'
    },
    callbacks: {
        open: function () {
            var map_options = {
                center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
                streetViewControl: false,
                zoom: 8
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map_options);

            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        }
    }
});
```

В коде выше я просто добавляю контейнер с Google Maps картой под фотографию. Проблема заключается в том, что карта вся серая. Не помогает даже вызов `trigger(map, "resize");`!

Вот [пример на CodePen](http://codepen.io/CMTV/pen/qrmqad), иллюстрирующий проблему.

Никак не могу разобраться, в чем же может быть проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дублирую ;)

Думаю дело в `type: image`

Переделала на `type: inline` (универсально для кастомного содержимого):

```js
$('.btn').magnificPopup({
  items: { 
    src: 
          '' +
          '<div class="mfp-figure">' +
          '<button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>' +
          '<img class="mfp-img" src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1080/">' +
          '<div class="mfp-bottom-bar"><div id="map"></div></div>' +
          '</div>',
    type: 'inline' 
  },
  callbacks: {
    open: function(){
      var map_options = {
                center: {lat: 55.753994, lng: 37.622093},
                //streetViewControl: false,
                zoom: 8
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), map_options);
          
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    }
  },
  
});
```

```css
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAUAAJjs1T751i6-4U__XnNCSQz-xXAelI&amp;libraries=places"></script>



<button class="btn btn-1">button 1</button>
<button class="btn btn-2">button 2</button>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/xqdaOz)

**P.S:** чуточку поменяла координаты карты, просто, для наглядности

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Правда, вокруг изображения появилась неприятная рамка... Никак не соображу, как ее убрать.

Comment: что-то не вижу рамки http://prntscr.com/eizcc7

Comment: они появляются, если изображение меньше, чем ширина окна браузера: http://prntscr.com/eizhp1

Comment: @CMTV, ну это уже стилями можно все поправить и задать как вам нужно. Откройте панель разработчика и посмотрите блоки. например 'рамку' можно убрать так: `.mfp-figure:after {content: none; }`

Comment: Спасибо. Все работает!